# Why doesn't pool.map initiate a new process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

I'm trying to run a member method in a separate subprocess. The member method is actually acting as a callback dispatcher loop where it executes each callback.

The issue I'm facing is that the callbacks never get called. The method which is responsible for spawning the new process does get executed but I get no output/signal from the actual dispatcher loop or the callback itself.

The new process is spawned using this snippet :

```py
def run_callback_disptacher(self):
    pool = pathos.multiprocessing.Pool(1)
    pool.map(self.execute_callbacks, [])
    print('run_callback_disptacher executed')
```

and the dispatcher callback is this:

```py
def execute_callbacks(self):
    print(f'dispatcher list: {self.callback_list}')
    while True:
        for callback in self.callback_list:
            callback()
```

I am using `pathos.multiprocessing` module in Windows10 and this is a minimal example demonstrating the issue:

```py
import time
import torch 
import torchvision
from torchvision import models
from torch.utils import mkldnn as mkldnn_utils
import pathos

class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self, model_name='r18', use_jit=False, use_mkldnn=False, device='cpu'):
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.use_jit = use_jit
        self.use_mkldnn = use_mkldnn 
        self.device = device
        self.callback_list = []
        self.is_running = False
        self._init_model()

    def _init_model(self):
        if self.model_name == 'r18':
            self.model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
        elif self.model_name == 'r50':
            self.model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Model name: '{self.model_name}' is not recognized.")

        self.model = self.model.to(self.device)
        self.model.eval()

        if self.use_mkldnn:
            self.model = mkldnn_utils.to_mkldnn(self.model)
        if self.use_jit: 
            self.model = self.load_jit_model()

    def load_jit_model(self, jit_path = 'model.jit'):
        dummy_input = torch.tensor(torch.rand(size=(1, 3, 224, 224)))
        model = torch.jit.trace(self.model, dummy_input)
        torch.jit.save(model, jit_path)
        return torch.jit.load(jit_path)

    def add_callback(self, callback):
        self.callback_list.append(callback)

    def remove_callback(self, callback):
        self.callback_list.remove(callback)

    def get_callbacks(self):
        return self.callback_list

    def execute_callbacks(self):
        print(f'dispatcher list: {self.callback_list}')
        while True:
            for callback in self.callback_list:
                callback()

    def start(self):
        self.is_running = True
        while self.is_running:
            # simulating a generic operation here
            time.sleep(0.2)
        print('start ended!')

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False

    def run_callback_disptacher(self):
        pool = pathos.multiprocessing.Pool(1)
        pool.map(self.execute_callbacks, [])
        print('run_callback_disptacher executed')
```

and this is how it is called :

```py
import threading
import time
from minimal_example import SomeClass

def simple_callback():
    print('hello from simple callback')

def start():
    obj = SomeClass(model_name='r18', use_jit=False, use_mkldnn=False, device='cpu')
    obj.add_callback(simple_callback)
    obj.run_callback_disptacher()
    starter = threading.Thread(target=obj.start)
    starter.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    print(obj.get_callbacks())
    obj.stop()
    print('Done!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This was supposed to be a minimal example showing why I get pickle error in my actual class! but for some reason I even cant get this to execute the method in question. 
Also here is the colab [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13kPvsPBNyRM0s0PkB3ABmo-0NecCy9eu#scrollTo=PJ1mf6i1gVSb) though running under linux vs windows is very different as windows is quite a hassle in this (due to spawning and pickle errors)

Comment: If it works on linux but not windows, I am going to assume that it's due to a bug that slipped into `dill` lately that affects the ability to pickle on windows.  The bug is fixed in `dill` master, and will soon be released.  I'd go grab `dill` from GitHub, and then see if that fixes your issue.  If not, let's work it out.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Thanks a lot. really appreciate it.

Comment: By the way I need  to add that, this very snippet doesn't work under Linux either (you can run the colab version) if I replace the multiprocess with threading it works but not with multi-threading. In anyway, this should be running under linux at least I dont know what I am missing here though!

Comment: So, it runs on linux and windows now... and the issue is that the callback is never called (or at least printed).  Can you check if, instead of printing, you wrote to a log/file or otherwise returned something?  If that works, then it's likely an issue of redirecting the stdout.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns , no files are being created either o returned. as I said it seems it(`execute_callbacks`) just doesn't get executed!

Comment: Two thoughts: (1) it's possible that when `execute_callbacks` gets called the `callback_list` is empty.  You should check that during the call (with a print). (2) It's generally not a good idea to create a `Pool` inside a class.  You will be creating pools for each class instance, and those pools have to all fight for resources.  I generally create a pool outside of the class, and then pass in the `map` function, or call the appropriate method on an external `map`. Creating a `Pool` inside a class means that the `Pool` is serialized and shipped along with the method, and that can cause issues.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Thanks a lot. The reason I'm doing this is that, the callbacks are actually coming from other languages (C++/C#,etc).The python module is exposed to the outside using C++.I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do that in this scenario. 
Also having everything self contained is sth that I'm after,it just makes life so easier in terms of maintenance and not relying on client side.
Concerning the `callback_list`, the execute block doesn't output anything. `callback_list` cant be empty, as the class is fully initialized, then the callback is added and then the multiprocess is instantiated

Comment: Is my assumption not correct?

Comment: Serialization does some strange things.  When serializing a class, it stores the class instance, the class definition, and all attributes.  These are not shared across processes, but they can be in threads. Check the callback_list, just to see what happens.  Also you might want to swap a `ProcessPool` with a `ThreadPool` to see if that does anything.  That will help get to the root cause.  It's almost always a serialization issue of some form.